# How to post uiimage instead of image url from fbconnect feed dialog?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to post uiimage (screenshot taken from app) instead of url to post in facebook from facebook dialog along with user option to enter text. how it can be achieved. some help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to post image in facebook through fbconnect few steps need to follow with the fbconnect api.

1. need to login in facebook then it check about the access key and the expiry date.
2. if those are not nil, there it go to post the image i.e

   ```
   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cellImageView.image);
   NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"app name",@"message",imageData,@"source", nil];
   [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
   ```

if not it go for the access key and expiry key and then to the image post code as written above.

for more download fbconnect api and look at the login and have a look on the code with brakepoints.

for this user need the login delegate and fb request delegate.

also don't forget to initialize  facebook obj with app id and to set its delegate self.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to post the photo part. I'm sure the text is just another field.

```
@try {
     // make sure your permissions are set
     NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
     @"publish_stream",
     nil];

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                           defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                              allowLoginUI:NO
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error){
                                             NSLog(@"completion handler.");
                                         }];



        [FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:imageToUpload
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (!error) {
                                       UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                                           initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                           message:@"Photo Uploaded!"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

                                       [tmp show];
                                   } else {
                                       UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                                           initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                           message:@"Error uploading image to Facebook."
                                                           delegate:self
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

                                       [tmp show];

                                   }
                               }];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"-----> !! ERROR UPLOADING IMAGE TO FACEBOOK !!");
    }
```

Comment: textfield is for posting string to wall